# PayPal Checkout popup down issue

Tags: swift, paypal

I had integrated PayPal Checkout for payment gateway. when I click on payment button then Popup open and showing message "Sending you back to the merchant side" and popup down without opening payment page.[here is related issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCOBW.png)

Here is my code-

**
Checkout.start(
createOrder: { createOrderAction in

```
               let amount = PurchaseUnit.Amount(currencyCode: .usd, value: "10.00")
               let purchaseUnit = PurchaseUnit(amount: amount)
               let order = OrderRequest(intent: .capture, purchaseUnits: [purchaseUnit])

               createOrderAction.create(order: order)

           }, onApprove: { approval in

               approval.actions.capture { (response, error) in
                   print("Order successfully captured: \(response?.data)")
               }

           }, onCancel: {

               // Optionally use this closure to respond to the user canceling the paysheet

           }, onError: { error in

               // Optionally use this closure to respond to the user experiencing an error in
               // the payment experience

           }
       )
    **
```

Comment: What is your question?  ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?  質問は何ですか？

Comment: @ElTomato I am getting this error form PayPal 

'The operation couldn’t be completed. (OrderActionError error 1.)'